# Metal mem_none vs mem_threadgroup

Tags: metal

The documentation in the [Metal Shading Language spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/metal-shading-language-specification.pdf#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364) is as follows:

- `mem_none` In this case, no memory fence is applied, and threadgroup_barrier acts only as an execution barrier.
- `mem_threadgroup` Ensure correct ordering of memory operations to threadgroup memory for threads in a threadgroup.

Does this mean whenever we are using threadgroup memory, we need to use `mem_threadgroup` for our barriers? If so, under what circumstances does `mem_none` suffice?

I've seen [code](https://github.com/mateuszbuda/GPUExample/blob/master/GPUExample/kernel.metal) where threadgroup memory is loaded, but `mem_none` is used (is this code incorect?). And yet another [example](https://github.com/jrprice/NBody-Metal/blob/master/NBody-Metal/shaders.metal) where `mem_threadgroup` is used.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Apple dev:

> The memflags set in the barrier tell the compiler which caches need to be flushed so that all threads can see the same thing when yoru code executes the barrier.  If you use mem_none, no caches will be flushed and it's undefined whether values written by one thread to any type of memory will be seen by any other thread.  If you set mem_threadgroup, you can be assured that any values written to threadgroup memory (and only threadgroup memory) can be seen by other threads after the barrier.
>
> So to answer your quesiton, if your kernel isn't dependant on values written from another thread into threadgroup memory, you can use mem_none.  But if you're using threadgroup memory in the first place, it's likely (but not a given) that you're using it to communicate between threads, so you'll probably want to set mem_threadgroup.

Answer (score 0):

According to do Metal Shading Language spec mem_threadgroup ensures the order of the threadgroup memory access operations.